# How do you store an output from a combobox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am trying to make my code so that I get an output from my ComboBox and then store it then the variable "Planet", how would I go about this? I have tried Planet=ComboBox1 but this does not work.

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Planet As String

    Planet = ComboBox1
    If Planet =


    End If

End Sub
```

---

I have now used:

```
Planet = Convert.ToString(ComboBox1)
```

but I get the output "System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 8", I have 8 Strings in this ComboBox and it seems that is what it is outputting. When I select an item in the ComboBox I click on one of the planets from a drop down list, which is what I need to retun.

Comment: help yourself to some research: [Combobox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry did not debugged it before SelectedText is the wrong property, you should only use it to retrieve the text that the user selected inside the textbox portion of the combobox. You do get all text selected after changing the index but that doesn't happen until after this event runs. Use SelectedItem.ToString() instead. here's the code:

```
' I have added a combobox and a lable and the code is written on SelectedIndexChanged Event

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Text1" Then
        Label1.Text = "Text1"
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Text2" Then
        Label1.Text = "Text2"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I do this for a NumericUpDown?

Comment: If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "1" Then
            Label1.Text = "1"
     End If

Comment: Sorry, I am now using a different tool, the NumericUpDown for me is to get the user to change a number which I then need outputting into another variable, how would I do this as SelectedItem doesn't work for NumericUpDowns

Comment: If NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString = "1" Then
            Label1.Text = "YourString"
        End If 'This will work on the valuechanged event of the NumbericUpDOwn...

Comment: Is there any way to stop a user typing in a number that's too high into a NumericUpDown? I have "Me.NumericUpDown1.Maximum = Max" where Max is a constant, but they can still type in a number that's higher than this maximum, how do I stop this?

Comment: Set the readonly property of the NumbericUpDown to true, maybee a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cod that may help:

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Planet As String

```
Planet = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.Tostring()
If Planet = "ConditionalValue" Then
'Your Code if True
ELSE
'YOUR CODE IF FALSE

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: For this to work do I need to have a confirmation button? I have tried to do this in the debug mode as it would only flag up 0 as the changed value from the IF's (which it shouldn't be). In the debug mode it wouldn't even go into the IF statement after and would bring up the form again, as if asking for an input.

Comment: Do check the new answer. Thanks.